# Integrals of the Form $\int_{0}^{1}f\left(bx\right)\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi ax\right)\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Recently I derived this result,
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi ax\right)\right)dx=\pi\left(\frac{a}{n+1}-\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)a^{n+1}}\sum_{j=1}^{a}j^{1+n}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{a}{n+2}\right)}$$
where, $a\in \text{I}$.

And thought why not do some "Integral Milking" With it.

Notice that the result contains a summation term which does not have a pleasant closed form.

But using Series Expansion of Functions we can arrive at results such as follows which have a closed form,

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{bx}\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi ax\right)\right)dx=\pi\left(\left(\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{a}{b^{2}}\right)e^{b}-\frac{1}{b}\frac{\left(e^{b}-1\right)e^{\frac{b}{a}}}{e^{\frac{b}{a}}-1}-\frac{1}{2b}-\frac{a}{b^{2}}\right)$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\cos\left(bx\right)\arctan\left(\cot\left(a\pi x\right)\right)dx=a\pi\left(\frac{1}{2ba}\cot\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)\left(\cos b-1\right)-\frac{\cos b}{b^{2}}+\frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(bx\right)\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi ax\right)\right)dx=\pi\left(\ \frac{1}{2b}\sin\left(b\right)\cot\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)-\ \frac{1}{2b}\cos\left(b\right)-\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{2a-1}{b}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{a}{b}\cos b-\frac{a}{b^{2}}\sin b\right)$$

I was wondering what more Interesting Integrals of such form can be derived, just looking for some inspiration.

$$\int_{0}^{1}f\left(bx\right)\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi ax\right)\right)dx$$

Comment: Does $I$ denote integers? If so, $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{N}$ for positive integers, is a more common notation. The sum $\sum_{1\le j\le a} j^{1+n}$ can be evaluated: it is [Faulhaber's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html).

Comment: @Integrand Yes it is for Integers, and I am aware of that formula but that ends up in another summation anyways so I thought to keep it as it is.

Comment: Also, $\arctan(\cot(\pi a x)) = \pi/2 - \pi * M(ax)$, where $M(z) = z\equiv 1$; this is commonly known as a sawtooth wave and can be expressed either as a fractional part, or as a Fourier series.

Comment: Try with polylogarithms for example.